# How to add a date for a specific time

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

For a dataframe like the one below, I want to add one day to the date only in the 0:00 time zone.
Is there any way to do it?

```
df.head(50)
```

[image: example]]

Comment: you do not include timezone in your DF so not sure how you can use timezone in your logic... are you asking to add one day to all times that are exactly midnight?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to say.
I'm not good at English, sorry.

Comment: Please add an example of your dataframe in text code mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
# create a mask for all entries with midnight as their time
row_mask = (df['timezone'].dt.hour == 0) & (df['timezone'].dt.minute == 0)
#now apply it
df.loc[row_mask,'timezone'] = df[row_mask]['timezone'] + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```